How would I evaluate this Gaussian integral with a square root?
$$f(a,b) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\sqrt{a^2+x^4} + b x}dx$$
Assuming $a$ is quite small.
When $a=0$ this is just a normal Gaussian integral with solution $f(0,b) = \sqrt{\pi}e^{b^2/4}$
I would like perhaps to get the answer in terms of a Taylor series in $a$. Unfortunately I run into difficulties evaluating the integrals in the terms.

I do not think that  a Taylor series in $a$ would be of any help since the integrals would diverge (except the first term tht you mentioned).

Is there another way to approximate the integral for small a perhaps?

I tried a few ways with no success at all. The simplest Padé approximant $$\frac{e^{b x-\sqrt{x^4}}}{\frac{a^2}{2   \sqrt{x^4}}+1}$$ does not integrate.

Because of symmetry you have $f(a,b) = f(a,-b)$, and thus
$$
f(a,b) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-\sqrt{a^2 + x^4}}\mathrm{cosh}(bx), \mathrm{d}x
$$
is another representation.

With hint of @Robert Lee and using Mellin Transform and Inverse Mellin Transform:
$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \exp \left(-\sqrt{a^2+x^4}\right) \cosh (b x) \, dx=\\\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \mathcal{M}_A\left[\exp \left(-A \sqrt{a^2+x^4}\right) \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{(b x)^{2 k}}{(2 k)!}\right](s) \, dx\right](1)=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }
   \mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \mathcal{M}_A\left[\frac{\exp \left(-A \sqrt{a^2+x^4}\right) (b x)^{2 k}}{(2 k)!}\right](s) \, dx\right](1)=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }
   \frac{(b x)^{2 k} \left(a^2+x^4\right)^{-\frac{s}{2}} \Gamma (s)}{(2 k)!} \, dx\right](1)=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{\left(1+(-1)^{2 k}\right) a^{\frac{1}{2}+k-s} b^{2 k} \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4} (1+2
   k)\right) \Gamma (s) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4} (-1-2 k+2 s)\right)}{4 (2 k)! \Gamma \left(\frac{s}{2}\right)}\right](1)=\\\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{2^{-\frac{5}{4}+\frac{k}{2}} \left(1+(-1)^{2 k}\right) a^{\frac{3}{4}+\frac{k}{2}} b^{2 k} K_{-\frac{3}{4}-\frac{k}{2}}(a)
   \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4} (1+2 k)\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } (2 k)!}=\\\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left(\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)_{-\frac{n}{2}} \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)_{\frac{n}{2}}
   \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)_{\frac{n}{2}} (1)_n\right) \left(\frac{a^2}{4}\right)^m \left(2 b^2\right)^n}{\left(\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)_{m-\frac{n}{2}} (1)_{2 n}\right) (m! n!)}+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \sum
   _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left(\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)_{-\frac{n}{2}} \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)_{\frac{n}{2}} \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)_{\frac{n}{2}} (1)_n\right) \left(\frac{a^2}{4}\right)^m \left(2
   b^2\right)^n}{\left(\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)_{m-\frac{n}{2}} (1)_{2 n}\right) (m! n!)}-\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2 a^{3/2} \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \sum _{m=0}^{\infty }
   \frac{\left(\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)_{-\frac{n}{2}} \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)_{\frac{n}{2}} \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)_{\frac{n}{2}} (1)_n\right) \left(\frac{a^2}{4}\right)^m \left(a b^2\right)^n}{\left((1)_{2 n}
   \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)_{m+\frac{n}{2}}\right) (m! n!)}}{6 \sqrt{\pi }}-\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2 a^{3/2} \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left(\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)_{-\frac{n}{2}}
   \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)_{\frac{n}{2}} \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)_{\frac{n}{2}} (1)_n\right) \left(\frac{a^2}{4}\right)^m \left(a b^2\right)^n}{\left((1)_{2 n} \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)_{m+\frac{n}{2}}\right) (m! n!)}}{6 \sqrt{\pi
   }}$$
where: $K$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind.
Four double infinty series can be expressed by: Srivastava - Daoust function
Asymptotics if a is small:
Using infinty series with BesselK function and using Mathematica:
 Asymptotic[Sum[Series[(
  2^(-(5/4) + k/2) (1 + (-1)^(2 k)) a^(3/4 + k/2) b^(2 k)
    BesselK[-(3/4) - k/2, a] Gamma[1/4 (1 + 2 k)])/(
  Sqrt[\[Pi]] (2 k)!), {a, 0, 2}] // Normal, {k, 0, 
 Infinity}], {a, 0, 2}] // FunctionExpand // Expand

$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \exp \left(-\sqrt{a^2+x^4}+b x\right) \, dx\approx e^{\frac{b^2}{4}} \sqrt{\pi }+a^2 e^{\frac{b^2}{4}} \sqrt{\pi }+\frac{1}{10} a^4 e^{\frac{b^2}{4}} \sqrt{\pi }-\frac{1}{240} a^4 b^2 e^{\frac{b^2}{4}} \sqrt{\pi }-\frac{1}{480} a^4 b^4 e^{\frac{b^2}{4}}
   \sqrt{\pi }-\frac{1}{2} a^2 b \pi  \text{erfi}\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{16} a^4 b \pi  \text{erfi}\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{960} a^4 b^5 \pi 
   \text{erfi}\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)-\frac{3 a^{3/2} \Gamma \left(-\frac{3}{4}\right)^2}{16 \sqrt{\pi }}-\frac{3 a^{7/2} \Gamma \left(-\frac{3}{4}\right)^2}{112 \sqrt{\pi }}+\frac{a^{7/2} b^4 \Gamma
   \left(-\frac{3}{4}\right)^2}{896 \sqrt{\pi }}+\frac{a^{5/2} b^2 \Gamma \left(-\frac{5}{4}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{8 \sqrt{\pi }}$$

Wow. That truly is a work of wonder! I didn't think it was even possible.
I checked your formula with a=0.01, b=0, this gives sqrt(pi)-0.00229485 .
With numerical integration I get sqrt(pi)-0.00229489
So this looks like it is correct to 5 significant figures for this value!
